# Joining MP3's via commandline with background track

Tags: linux, audio, command-line, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm already taking advatage of two command line utilities. I'm using ffmpeg to convert m4a to mp3, and then I'm combining a few mp3's into one large one using mp3wrap. The resulting file is something like this:

```
BackgroundMusic.mp3 > Audio1.mp3 > Audio2.mp3
```

I need something more like

```
Audio1.mp3 > Audio2.mp3
|_____________________|
           |
  BackgroundMusic.mp3
```

To where the background music runs continuously in the background. Would be nice to be able to change the volume of each track too.

Does anyone know a command line program like mp3wrap but can also add in a background track?

I will not be able to use a GUI program such as Audacity, as all of this will be automated on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use sox: first concatenate the 2 audio files, then mix with background

Comment: @gengisdave I'm looking at sox now, but can you provide the command to be able to mix a background track? Thanks

Comment: given two input files, sox concatenates them by deafult, unless you use the `-m` switch; take a look at the docs, you can also change the volume or apply effects

Comment: @gengisdave That works! I have the background music now. Can you suggest a way to lower the volume of the mixed track now?

Comment: `--volume value` will change the volume of the file that follow in the command line; value < 1 decrease, value > 1 increase

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with FFmpeg alone.

```
ffmpeg -i input_audio1 -i input_audio2 -i input_background_audio -filter_complex "
aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];
[0:a]volume=volume=0.1[volume0];
[1:a]volume=volume=0.1[volume1];
[2:a]volume=volume=0.1[volume2];
[s1][volume1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];
[volume0][ac1]amix=inputs=2[amixed1];
[amixed1][volume2]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" output_audio
```

You need to use `filter_complex` to chain all the filters that you are going to use for adjusting the volumes, silent spaces, concat, etc. filters.

As the first step you can concatenate two audio files that you need to play one after the other. To do that I have first created and silent audio using [`aevalsrc`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aevalsrc) filter with the same duration as the first audio clip. Then use [`concat`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1) filter to concatenate silent audio and the second audio.
To adjust the audio I have used [`volume`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#volume) filter. You can adjust the volume values accordingly. To mix the audios you can use [`amix`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#amix) filter. You can specify `duration` attribute to get the first input which is `[amixed1]` duration. With that option you can stop the whole audio with the duration of audio1+audio2 without play it for the full duration of background audio duration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works pretty nicely, however the result comes out very quiet. I had to make the 'volume=50' to even make it normal, but then it obviously sounds terrible cause it's peaking. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @Brandon The default value for volume is "1.0" which does not change the original volume of the source. See the [reference](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#volume).